# In Python, how would you properly annotate a function to show the same return type as a function of a class member?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.11

I'm using Python 3.11 with mypy as my type checker. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Generic

class MyBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Bar(MyBase):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 5

class Baz(MyBase):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
        return 'Hello'

T = TypeVar('T', bound=MyBase)

@dataclass
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    value: T

    def foo_call(self) -> ???:  # What do I put here? I want something like T.my_func.__annotations__['return']
        return self.value.my_func()

myFoo: Foo[Bar] = Foo(value=Bar())
myFoo.foo_call()  # this should give a return type-hint of int
```

I could just declare myFoo as a Foo[int], with foo_call(self) -> T, but then that wouldn't properly update if any changes are made to the return type of Bar.my_func. What's the proper way to do this?

## EDIT

user2357112's method is helpful, but still requires updating the type hint in multiple places when the return type of my_func changes. It also requires the use of multiple TypeVars if I want to support multiple functions. For example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

# need to add an additional TypeVar for every method I want to support
T = TypeVar('T')
TOther = TypeVar('TOther')

class MyBase(ABC, Generic[T, TOther]):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def other_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> TOther:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Bar(MyBase[int, float]):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 5

    def other_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> float:
        return 6.2


@dataclass
class Foo(Generic[T, TOther]):
    value: MyBase[T, TOther]

    def foo_call(self) -> T:
        return self.value.my_func()

    def foo_other(self) -> TOther:
        return self.value.other_func()

myFoo: Foo[int, float] = Foo(value=Bar())
myFoo.foo_call()
myFoo.foo_other()
```

I'd ideally like to be able to just pass the type of MyBase as the generic type hint for myFoo (e.g. myFoo: Foo[Bar] = ...) and then have the return types of methods like foo_call and foo_other be inferred from that.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, MyBase should be generic, and Foo's parameter should be the `my_func` return type, not the `MyBase` subclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyBase(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Bar(MyBase[int]):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 5

class Baz(MyBase[str]):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
        return 'Hello'

@dataclass
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    value: MyBase[T]

    def foo_call(self) -> T:
        return self.value.my_func()
```

Comment: That works, but does required changing the type hint in at least different places if the return type of my_func ever changes. Mypy does at least warn me now when the return_type of my_func does change.

class Bar(MyBase[NewType]):
    def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs) -> NewType: ...

myFoo: Foo[NewType] = Foo(value=Bar())

I'd also potentially like to be able to support multiple methods of MyBase without having to create another TypeVar for each. Ideally, I could just use the type of MyBase as the type hint for Foo and it would automatically infer the return type for all used methods.

Comment: @Mobious fortunately python's type system is not typescript-like, and generics work only in one direction. If you need several type variables, just add them.